# Time Machine Synchronize just my Home Folder to external hard drive in MacOS Leopard

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, backup, time-machine

Just bought an external 500GB hard drive. I want to store, backup and synchronize just my home folder in Mac OS Leopard.

I dont want all the system preferences to be backed up. I don't want other user's home folder to be backed up. Just my home folder backup and synchronization is enough for.

Is TimeMachine suitable for this customization ? Will my applications also get backed up using TimeMachine ?

Please help

Answer (score 4):

Select *Options…* in *System Preferences » Time Machine* and specify which directories you *don't* want backed up.

Once you select `/System` there, Time Machine offers to exclude all system folders.

[image]

To be sure, you can exclude them explicitly (especially if you use a UNIX package manager such as Homebrew, Fink or Macports that uses `/opt` which doesn't exist by default): The system also has certain folders that are hidden by default (such as `/bin`). You can click the + button in that dialog and them press `Cmd-Shift-.` (or check *Show invisible items* in the file dialog) to display hidden files and folders to select them for exclusion from backup. Do this for all folders directly in your disk's root folder except `Users`.

Then exclude all users (`/Users/Wife` etc.) except yourself.

[image]

Once this is done and you backed up your data once, open the backup volume and navigate to `Backups.backupdb/MachineName/Date` and check to see if everything was excluded as you wanted.

---

Regarding your applications, it depends where they're installed. If you install to `/Applications`, you should not exclude that from backup. If you install to `~/Applications` (in your home directory), you can proceed as described above.

You can also move most third party applications (those not installed using an installer) to `~/Applications` to have them automatically be included in the home directory backup.

---

Remember that the system itself is quite small, with *by far* the most data being in users' home directories and the applications folders; these also being the folders most frequently changed. Useless (for backups) stuff like your hibernation memory image and temporary directories is excluded from Time Machine anyway.

Backing up those folders is really not a problem, storage-wise. Keeping your exclusions list up to date is.

---

You might want to take a look at *Carbon Copy Cloner* or *SuperDuper!*, which are more configurable. Time Machine is really intended as a complete system backup.